# jquery category subcategory, subcategory, etc

Tags: jquery

I want to do a three-level hierarchical category, subcategory and sub-subcategory with select tag using JQuery. Actually, it works. But, there is a bug. It only works for the first time. When I choose a category, it shows subcategory. Then, when I choose subcategory, it shows sub-subcategory. That's good. But, when I change category without reloading the page, it shows duplicate subcategories. I don't know why, but I think it might be due to not understanding JQuery live function. Here is the code. There are some twig tags (from Symfony 2) used.

Please, help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = '<select><option value="0">--Select--</option>';
        {% for catalog in catalogs %}
            options += '<option value="{{ catalog.id }}">{{ catalog.name }}</option>';
        {% endfor %}
        options += '</select>';
        $('#form_item_add').html(options);

        $('#form_item_add select').change(function() {
            $(this).nextAll($(this)).remove();
            $.getJSON('{{ path('subcatalog_list') }}', {catalog: $(this).val()}, function(json) {
                if (json.length !== 0)
                {
                    options = '<select><option value="0">--Select--</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
                    {
                        options += '<option value="' + json[i].c_id + '">' + json[i].c_name + '</option>';
                    }
                    options += '</select>';
                    $('#form_item_add').append(options);

                    $('#form_item_add select').live('change', function() {
                        $(this).nextAll($(this)).remove();
                        $.getJSON('{{ path('subcatalog_list') }}', {catalog: $(this).val()}, function(json) {
                            if (json.length !== 0)
                            {
                                options = '<select><option value="0">--Select--</option>';
                                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
                                {
                                    options += '<option value="' + json[i].c_id + '">' + json[i].c_name + '</option>';
                                }
                                options += '</select>';
                                $('#form_item_add').append(options);

                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My Controller (Symfony 2)

```
/**
 * @Route("/subcatalogs", name = "subcatalog_list")
 */
public function getSubcatalogAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TradeTradeBundle:Catalog');
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.parent = :parent')
            ->setParameter('parent', $request->get('catalog'))
            ->getQuery();
        $subcatalogs = $query->getScalarResult();

        return new Response(json_encode($subcatalogs));
    }

    return $this->render('TwigBundle:Exception:error.html.twig', array('status_code' => 404, 'status_text' => 'Page not found'));
}
```

Comment: u r using three drop down list ?

Comment: Yes, I am. Thank you for your attention, ThulasiRam. But, they are dynamically generated, not just first disabled and then enabled.

Comment: k.. i will do it. second and third drop down list alone will be changeable?

Comment: Well, yes. Let's say. I have a category of computer, car, etc. When I choose a computer category, it shows subcategories (laptop, desktop, etc). When I choose a laptop subcategory, it shows sub-subcategories (Asus, Macbook, etc). It works. But, when I change the category to car then back again to computer, it shows duplicate categories (two select drop down holding identical info: laptop, desktop, etc). :)

Comment: k.. first drop down list dynamically binded?

Comment: I just loaded it using JQuery, not just html. Actually, it does not matter. I think the problem it with live function. Because when I debugged it using opera dragonfly, the second time when chose computer category, change event ran twice (first change and second binded change functions with live function). I don't know why. :)

Comment: '{{ path('subcatalog_list') }}' is same for subcategory and sub-subcategory also?

Comment: Yes, it is a path to url which runs the function that gets a category, subcategory and sub-subcategory. It does not matter.

Comment: k.. u can show me the output of json result?

Comment: I just uploaded my controller function. {{ path('subcatalog_list') }} is a path to getSubcatalogAction() function. There is a route annotation with url name "subcatalog_list".

Comment: getSubcatalogAction() this is k. for getsub-SubcatalogAction() method name? i don no about php. u can show this output of alert(JSON.stringify(json));

Comment: The output of alert(JSON.stringify(json));  [{"c_id":12,"c_name":"Laptop"},{"c_id":13,"c_name":"Desktop"},{"c_id":14,"c_name":"Netbook"}]

Comment: The output of alert(JSON.stringify(json)); for second $.getJSON?

Comment: getSubcatalogAction() is for category, subcategory and sub-subcategory. It does not matter for the function. Because they are all categories in one table with fields id, name, parent. If parent is null then it is category. If not, it is either subcategory or sub-subcategory. So, the getSubcatalogAction() function handles all of the them.

Comment: The same [{"c_id":15,"c_name":"Asus"},{"c_id":16,"c_name":"Toshiba"},{"c_id":17,"c_name":"Macbook"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = '<select><option value="0">--Select--</option>';
        {% for catalog in catalogs %}
            options += '<option value="{{ catalog.id }}">{{ catalog.name }}</option>';
        {% endfor %}
        options += '</select>';
        $('#form_item_add').html(options);

        $('#form_item_add select').live('change', function() {
            $(this).nextAll($(this)).remove();
            $.getJSON('{{ path('subcatalog_list') }}', {catalog: $(this).val()}, function(json) {
                if (json.length !== 0)
                {
                    options = '<select><option value="0">--Select--</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
                    {
                        options += '<option value="' + json[i].c_id + '">' + json[i].c_name + '</option>';
                    }
                    options += '</select>';
                    $('#form_item_add').append(options);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var ddlCategory = '<select id="ddlCategory"><option value="0">--Select--</option>';
            {% for catalog in catalogs %}
            ddlCategory += '<option value="{{ catalog.id }}">{{ catalog.name }}</option>';
            {% endfor %}
            ddlCategory += '</select>';
            $('#form_item_add').html(options);

            $('#form_item_add').find('select.ddlCategory').on('change', function () {
                $(this).nextAll('select').remove();

                if ($(this).val() !== '0') {
                    $.getJSON('{{ path(' + subcatalog_list + ') }}', { catalog: $(this).val() }, function (json) {
                        if (json.length !== 0) {
                            var ddlSubcategory = $('<select id="ddlSubcategory"><option value="0">--Select--</option></select>');
                            $.each(json, function (i, entity) {
                                ddlSubcategory.append($('<option />', { 'value': entity.c_id, 'text': entity.c_name }));
                            });

                            $('#form_item_add').append(ddlSubcategory);

                            $('#form_item_add').find('select.ddlCategory').trigger('change');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#form_item_add select.ddlSubcategory').on('change', function () {
                $(this).nextAll('select').remove();

                if ($(this).val() !== '0') {
                    $.getJSON('{{ path(' + subcatalog_list + ') }}', { catalog: $(this).val() }, function (json) {
                        if (json.length !== 0) {
                            var ddlSubcategoryList = '<select id="ddlSubcategoryList"></select>';

                            $.each(json, function (i, entity) {
                                ddlSubcategoryList.append($('<option />', { 'value': entity.c_id, 'text': entity.c_name }));
                            });

                            $('#form_item_add').append(ddlSubcategoryList);

                            $('#form_item_add').find('select.ddlSubcategoryList').trigger('change');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. {{ path('subcatalog_list') }} is right. Don't worry about the path. It is just Symfony 2 twig. It works perfectly. The problem is with JQuery :)